# Implement Linux shell in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am making a shell as practice, but I am pretty struggling with a problem. Almost all commands work well, except "cd". I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argk, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    int             frkRtnVal;  
    char           *v[NV];  
    char           *sep = " \t\n";
    int             i;      

    while (1)
    {
        fgets(line, NL, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);

        if (feof(stdin))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EOF pid %d feof %d ferror %d\n", getpid(), feof(stdin), ferror(stdin));
            exit(0);
        }

        if (line[0] == '#' || line[0] == '\n' || line[0] == '\000')
        {
            continue;
        }

        v[0] = strtok(line, sep);
        for (i = 1; i < NV; i++)
        {
            v[i] = strtok(NULL, sep);
            if (v[i] == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        frkRtnVal = fork();
        switch (frkRtnVal)
        {
            case -1:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 0: 
            {
                execvp(v[0], v);
            }
            default:            
            {
                wait(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you can't fork and exec `cd`; it is a shell built-in because the shell has to execute the `chdir()` system call itself.  (More accurately, you can fork and exec `cd` (there's a `/usr/bin/cd` on Mac OS X, for example), but it doesn't do anything because the child shell exits immediately after changing directory and hasn't changed the directory of the main shell anyway.)

Comment: You are running into this problem because `cd` is not a program, at least not in a traditional sense. `cd` is a shell built-in command (type `man builtin` or `man cd` to learn more). This means that the logic for `cd` and the other shell built ins are built into the shell program as opposed to being an external program that is called by the shell through the traditional process of forking and execing. This can be verified by seeing there is no `cd` program in `/bin`.

Comment: (Initial duplicate wasn't read carefully enough; the problem there was newline as part of directory name.  Nevertheless, there is at least one suitable duplicate for this on SO.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot! That really helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems changing working directory in child process isn't affecting the parent process and therefore its effect isn't holded in the shell. You will have to parse it in the shell and treat it as a special command.